# Virtual machine does not seem to detect my GPU as 'primary'

Tags: windows, gentoo, qemu, vga-passtrough

If I enable a cirrus gpu this way : '-vga cirrus' while passing through my GPU, the cirrus display will be stuck at starting windows and the GPU will display windows properly.

And if I put not vga display at all, '-vga none', then the GPU display will be stuck at starting windows.

Also, with both activated, vnc only display the cirrus display and by no mean wants to display the GPU display.

Sorry if it's confusing, I'm doing my best.
So I'm thinking that my dedicated GPU is not set as primary by the bios or windows 7 itself, and I wonder how I could get through that ?

On Windows 10, there was no such issue and everything worked perfectly, just that the OS sucks.

Also, the host is running Gentoo GNU/Linux.

Here is my QEMU script :

```
#!/bin/bash
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=sdl 
export QEMU_SDL_SAMPLES=2048
# Windows 7 Virtual Machine - Aimed at playing video games, using GPU Passthrough
sudo vfio-bind 0000:01:00.0 0000:01:00.1
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 8192 \
  -bios /usr/share/edk2-ovmf/OVMF.fd \
  -cpu host,kvm=off \
  -smp 8,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=2 \
  -net nic,model=virtio \
  -net user  \
  -rtc base=utc \
  -vga none \
  -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0 \
  -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1 \
 \
  -drive file=/storage/sshd/vm/windows.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw,cache=none \
  -cdrom /storage/sshd/download/virtio.iso \
```

Comment: Please update your question with output from `lshw` and or `lspci`